# SSIS: How to move failure file's' to fail folder step by step

Tags: ssis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmrfe.png)

My program is to load all CSV file from source folder(1 CSV file = 1 row data) into database, then moved successful executed file to archived folder and if the file is failed to load into database, it will transfer into fail folder. Let say I have 100 files, 5 of it is failed and need to go into fail folder but my program only move 1 out of 5 and the other 4 still inside source folder. How can this happen ? I'm new to SSIS and do not have any experience in C# and other language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executed manually inside the visual studio application by press F5, it will always move 1 file of the fail file. So u need to configure it at SQL Server Agent to retry the program multiple time so that all the failed file move to fail folder